# How to sync Recharts chart with something custom that is not a Recharts graph

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

Currently, you can easily sync two charts by using the `syncId` property, like [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alidingling/nskpgcrz/).

I'd like to design something with D3, outside of Recharts scope. Is it possible to catch events or callbacks allowing me to sync my custom component the same way two Recharts components does?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, asked question too fast, before taking time to search deeper. AFAIK, this is not something written in documentation and encouraged, but you totally can rely on the internal event emitter to listen for sync events and trigger also sync events.

My code

```
import { eventCenter, SYNC_EVENT } from 'recharts/lib/util/Events';

// [...]

eventCenter.on(SYNC_EVENT, (cId, chartId, data) => {
  console.log(cId, chartId, data);
});

// [...]
```

Inspired by [the actual component behaviour here](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/blob/f14230a004192e70fd41176103a4b0ce4a0e9826/src/chart/generateCategoricalChart.js#L816)

Answer (score 0):

@guillaumepotier, did you test your approach?

From what I see you cant just trigger events after importing eventCenter, because you are not going to get the same instance that the recharts chart has. Every import returns a new instance of eventcenter, so even if you trigger the event, the chart wont receive it because its not the same eventcenter.

Comment: Now you're writing this it makes totally sense, but I can assure you my current implementation is working.. I do not have time now to investigate further now but if it's important for you tell me I'll try to take some time this week to look at it. Best